# OMP parallel for does not speed up the loop a lot although processor load goes 100 percent

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to speed up a few calculations but although all cores are busy with my calculations there is not much speed-up.

Runs on an I7 7800 (6 cores, 12 threads) with Windows 10 64 bit.

```
#include "omp.h"
int i;
int j;
double tempval1;
double tempval2;
double tempval3;
int col1=4;
int row1=37500000;
double *in1 = (double *)malloc(col1 * row1 * sizeof (double));
double *inim1 = (double *)malloc(col1 * row1 * sizeof (double));
double *in2 = (double *)malloc(col1 * row1 * sizeof (double));
double *inim2 = (double *)malloc(col1 * row1 * sizeof (double));
double *in8 = (double *)malloc(col1 * sizeof (double));


omp_set_num_threads(12);

    for (i = 0; i < col1; ++i)
    {
        tempval3=in8[i];// in8 individual for each column
        #pragma omp parallel for private(tempval1,tempval2),schedule(dynamic,16384)
        for (j = i * row1; j < ((i + 1) * row1); ++j)
        {
            //For each element of the matrix, multiply in1 with in2, both real and imaginary part, but beforehand add in8 to in2 (only real and without altering original in2)
            tempval1=inim1[j] * inim2[j];// 
            tempval2=in1[j] * inim2[j];// 
            in1[j]=in1[j] * (in2[j] + tempval3) - tempval1;// only add to in2 but not inim2 because in8 is not complex
            inim1[j]=inim1[j] * (in2[j] + tempval3) + tempval2;  
        }
    }
```

For example col1 is 4 and row1 is 37500000.
With one core I get 0.23 seconds, with 2 cores 0.19 seconds, with 12 cores 0.163 seconds, which is not even double speed.
With or without shedule or static vs. dynamic schedule does not really make any difference.
I can not create a temporary matrix for in1 because of lack of enough memory.
False sharing should not happen because with such high row1 numbers the individual chunks should be far appart, right?
Does anyone see an obvious mistake on my side?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain how you measure time.

Comment: I don't really know c. This is just a small piece of code that is called from a program that supplies the variables etc.
I added a few definitions and hope that this code is now executable.
The time is measured in the programm that calls this code.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious mistake I've noticed at glance is your assumption that multi-threading is coastless. But it is not. You will never get 4x speed up with 4 threads since there are costs on initializing each thread and merging them later. Even more perfomance gain (in %) tends to lower with more threads added which is clearly seen on your measurements. To better understand basic concepts of multi-threading you should read some basic programming book.

I think you should try using

```
#pragma omp for
```

directive with outer loop. OMP is high-perfomance threading library but programmer should put its directives in better places or at least try different variants if there is not obvious one.

And as I remember on my experience with OMP `omp_set_num_threads(12);` is just a recommendation to use 12 threads.

It's very good optimization practice to measure speed of different approaches, you are on the right way.

Comment: "You will never get 4x speed up with 4 threads" this is not true. You may have even more than 4 times if you have a NUMA architecture

Comment: Ok, NUMA architecture is another case. I bore in mind general multithreaded architecture built on single or multiple CPU cores.